# SSH server not started on boot (/boot/ssh present)

Tags: ssh

Hi I just recently acquired a pi and wanted to start using it right away and play with it a bit.

Unfortunately I don't have any network cable or screen + keyboard to use for initial setup.

So I looked up how to connect to wifi on boot, used nmap to find it on my network and tried to ssh unto it.

Turns out ssh server is disabled by default. So I create a file named ssh in /boot, retstarted my PI expecting to finaly be able to connect to it.

I guess I missed something because the port 22 is still not open.
Do you know what I missed?

what I know for sure:
* PI is connected to network
* ssh file exist in /boot
* 22 port is not open

Thank you

Comment: This is unanswerable because you have specified **NO** detail; what OS, what you have tried, what does work. How do you know it is not working?

Comment: @goldilocks gave me an answer to my issue.
To give you the missing details that I should have included in my first post,
The OS is Debian
I tried ssh and nmap on the raspberry's IP and couldn't connect because the port wasn't opened. I tried to put a file named ssh in the boot folder. I turned out that I put it in the wrong boot folder. I had put it on the moint point for the boot partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately I don't have any network cable or screen + keyboard to use for initial setup [...] So I create a file named ssh in /boot, retstarted my PI expecting to finaly be able to connect to it.

I'm going to connect the dots and assume since you could not do the initial set-up with the Pi running, you did this by editing the `/boot` folder on the second partition somewhere.

If so, then that won't work; `/boot` is a mount point for the first partition when the system is running.

You want to put that file in the first partition on the card, which is small (~60 MB) and contains a (V-) FAT32 filesystem with a dozen or so files and a single folder (`overlays`).

## OR

You created a `/boot` folder on the first partition and put it in there.  If so just move the `ssh` file one level up and remove the folder you created.

Comment: You got it right I did the first thing. Thanks for the explanation, I'll try to make it work.